# res.redirect does not reload the page to the new endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a login page for a quiz application. On pressing the login button, I'm sending a post request to the server, the server the redirects to the home page where the questions are listed. The problem is that it only refreshes the login page.

```
  // FRONT-END code
  const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // I only put this in to reload the page somehow
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    window.location.href = '/';
  };

  xhr.open('POST', '/login');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    username,
    password,
  }));
```

```
// SERVER-SIDE code
router.post('/login', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.username === undefined || req.body.password === undefined) {
    console.log('Doesn\'t have neccesarry elements');
    res.status(400).render('error', { message: 'Doesn\'t have necessary elements' });
  } else {
    ...
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

I would like to mention that the `/` is also a template rendered page, maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on your FRONTEND, if client request the server using xml request it is doesn't redirect the page. So you have to redirect from client `window.location.href` after the xml request.

1.If it is error on servee Sent `{status: error}`  to client like that,
2. check the status in the client if it is error change the path in clinen.

Comment: so I have unintentionally just written the correct syntax?

Comment: @BalogSzilárd Yes